# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession in scala eclipse

Tags: apache-spark

I have written a Spark Job in Java in scala eclipse. If I submit the Job using spark-submit command then it is working fine. but when I run the application in scala eclipse, it gives below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession

it gives error in below line code

```
val SPARK_SESSION = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark-job1").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: That means your project's classpath is not configured correctly. How have you set up your dependencies?

Comment: yes i have already setup dependencies and it was working fine before.but suddenly it give this error